# How to send bulk data in url?

Tags: python, django, get

I have to send bulk data items via url to process in server side.

Is it possible to send using get method?

```
 list1 = ["string1","string2","string3","string4"]
 list2 = ["domain_string1","domain_string2"]

 url = http://127.0.0.1/search?l=list1&l2=list2
```

How these lists should be passed?

These list of items will grow dynamically.sometime we will get 10 items in each list

suggest me the way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, it's best to avoid long query strings in GET requests. A great question for reference on this is the SO question [What is the maximum length of a URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url). You don't want to exceed 2000 characters.

If your items will always fit in this length, you can use [urllib.urlencode](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlencode) to convert your parameters:

```
>>> list1 = ["string1","string2","string3","string4"]
>>> list2 = ["domain_string1","domain_string2"]
>>> allparams = map(lambda x: ("list1", x), list1)
>>> allparams += map(lambda x: ("list2", x), list2)
>>> import urllib
>>> urllib.urlencode(allparams)
'list1=string1&list1=string2&list1=string3&list1=string4&list2=domain_string1&list2=domain_string2'
```

Instead, you could use a POST request. I highly recommend the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/v0.10.7/index.html) library:

```
import requests
r = requests.post("http://127.0.0.1/search", data=allparams)
```

Comment: The appropriate way to send them would be ?l1=string1&l1=string2&l2=string3, etc. That's the standard for URL formatting.

Comment: Right, I forgot that you can duplicate query params. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can send it all with the same url variable name

```
"http://localhost/search?urlvar=1&urlvar=2&urlvar=3"
```

request.GET.getlist("urlvar");